# v4.21 | User Feature not registering "user" State

Tags: spartacus-storefront

After installing the user feature via `ng add @spartacus/user`, Spartacus throws an error opening the address book:
[image]

The `state` in the selector is undefined because Spartacus does not register the `user` state.
I installed the checkout, ASM and organization features and for those the state is correctly appearing.
[image]

I followed the migration process from v3 to v4.

Any tips on how to proceed?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by importing `UserTransitional_4_2_Module` which registers the state.

The documentation doesn't mention it so I bet it's not the optimal way but it's a workaround for now.